# Access body of the POST request inside Erlang httpd

Tags: erlang

I get a POST request with a string representing a JSON object.

The `_Env` list looks like this:

```
[
  {server_software,"inets/6.3"},
  {server_name,"XTR20160414"},
  {gateway_interface,"CGI/1.1"},
  {server_protocol,"HTTP/1.1"},
  {server_port,9000},
  {request_method,"POST"},
  {remote_addr,"127.0.0.1"},
  {peer_cert,undefined},
  {script_name,"/api/server:auth"},
  {http_host,"localhost:9000"},
  {http_accept,"application/json"},
  {http_content_type,"application/json"},
  {http_content_length,"34"},
  {http_connection,"close"},
  {content_length,34}
]
```

My code to start server is:

```
start() ->
    mnesia:start(),
    inets:start(httpd, [
        {modules, [
            mod_alias,
            mod_auth,
            mod_esi,
            mod_actions,
            mod_cgi,
            mod_dir,
            mod_get,
            mod_head,
            mod_log,
            mod_disk_log
        ]},
        {port, 9000},
        {server_name, "pokerspace"},
        {server_root, "misc/log"},
        {document_root, "misc/www"},
        {erl_script_alias, {"/api", [server]}},
        {error_log, "error.log"},
        {security_log, "security.log"},
        {transfer_log, "transfer.log"},
        {mime_types, [
            {"json", "application/json"},
            {"html", "text/html"},
            {"css", "text/css"},
            {"js", "application/x-javascript"}
        ]}
    ]).
```

Then I make a POST request to this url with some data inside:

```
http://localhost:9000/api/server:auth
```

And handle this request with this code:

```
auth(SessionID, _Env, _Input) ->
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, [
        text_header(),
        "authenticated"
    ]).
```

I see that `content_length` is 34, which looks a proper number so the data seems to be coming in.

Now, how do I extract the posted data to go something with it?

Comment: Can you please add some code on how/from where you got this env list?

Comment: Please have a look at the details I had added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST body is passed to the callback function as the third argument as mentioned in the [mod_esi docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mod_esi.html#Module:Function-3).

This will return the passed in body concatenated with itself:

```
auth(SessionID, _Env, Input) ->
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, [
        Input, Input
    ]).
```

Demo:

```
$ curl -XPOST -d "hi" http://localhost:9000/api/server:auth
hihi
```

Comment: I supposed so but first time I tried it, it didn't work for some reason, may be some small things I missed, now works as expected. Thanks!